# Duplicate results Infinite scrolling API PHP

Tags: php, ajax, api

I am doing infinite ajax scrolling with php and api but my data is repeating. i don't want to load data  when user is end of page(run perfectly) . What i want when user reach at certain div(check_onload) then load the data but in this case data is repeating.Here is below my code how i stop repeating data.

```
<div id="post-data"></div>
<div style="display:none;" class="ajax-load"></div>
<div class="check_onload"></div>




<script type="text/javascript">

///this run Perfectly
 $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
            var token = $(".tokenId").val();
            GetMoreData(token);
        }
    });



    ///Repeating or duplication the data
   $(window).on('scroll',function() {
        if (checkVisible($('#check_onload'))) {
            var token = $(".tokenId").val();
            GetMoreData(token);

        } else {

        }
    });

    function checkVisible( elm, eval ) {
        eval = eval || "object visible";
        var viewportHeight = $(window).height(), // Viewport Height
            scrolltop = $(window).scrollTop(), // Scroll Top
            y = $(elm).offset().top,
            elementHeight = $(elm).height();

        if (eval == "object visible") return ((y < (viewportHeight + scrolltop)) && (y > (scrolltop - elementHeight)));
        if (eval == "above") return ((y < (viewportHeight + scrolltop)));
    }


   function GetMoreData(token){
      $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/loadMoreData.php?token=' + token,
                type: "get",
                beforeSend: function()
                {
                    $('.ajax-load').show();
                }
            })
            .done(function(data)
            {
                $('.ajax-load').hide();
                $("#post-data").append(data.html);
                $("#tokenId").val(data.token);
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
                  alert('server not responding...');
            });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you not think it important to include your PHP code that actually produces the data in your question? How does it use `token`? Also, you appear to be using the `.tokenId` selector to read the token but you're using `#tokenId` to write it. That could be your problem (not that we can see any elements with either a `tokenId` class or id attribute)

Comment: thanks for reply please see my updated code. Regarding token for each data load token is available for next record just like paging.

Comment: How do you expect different data since you dont pass any different parameters to your php

Comment: @AyushBhargava you have not updated your question at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 window scroll events being triggered, causing duplicates because you are requesting data from the server with the same token twice, each time the user scrolls the page.  I will have to assume that removing 1 of them will fix your problem.

Without seeing your server code,  this is the only solution.